# best ways allowing a group to edit some /etc files

Tags: security, sudo, vi

we have a group called JBossAdmins and users of this group must edit some /etc files on a RHEL 6:

- /etc/httpd/*
- /etc/java/*
- /etc/jboss/*

my first idea was to give the following sudo permissions:

```
%JBossAdmins ALL=(root) /bin/vi /etc/httpd/*
%JBossAdmins ALL=(root) /bin/vi /etc/java/*
%JBossAdmins ALL=(root) /bin/vi /etc/jboss/*
```

Obviously, the users can now start the vi as root and then edit any file by executing f.e. `:e /etc/passwd`

So sudo is not a good idea.

Then it came into my mind to do a `chgrp JBossAdmins -R path` and then a `chmod g+rw -R path`.

But i'm not quite sure whether this is a good idea either.

So considering the security implications, what's the best practice allowing a group of users to edit some /etc file? Are there any better alternatives than sudo or chgrp/chmod?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Giving someone `sudo` in `vi` is always a bad idea. They can get out of vi with a root-shell by issuing the `:shell` command. You don't want that.

An alternative for you might be `sudoedit`.
You can then give your users/groups rights for `sudoedit` in the `sudoers`-file:

```
%JBossAdmins <hostname>: sudoedit /etc/httpd/*
%JBossAdmins <hostname>: sudoedit /etc/java/*
%JBossAdmins <hostname>: sudoedit /etc/jboss/*
```

Comment: wow... that's what i'm looking for! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You could use acls instead and do something like

```
    setfacl -m g:JBossAdmins:rw /path/to/file
```

which would grant r/w permission to anyone in the JBossAdmins group to the specific files.

Comment: This is exactly what you should do. Using `sudo` is a clunky solution. How about if they use a different editor? Or if the want to use `less` or `cat`

Comment: Why is it better to use ACLs in this case than conventional groups, as OP suggested with `chgrp`? Isn't this exactly why group permissions exist?

Comment: Per OP, the files are in /etc. Files/directories in /etc/ have user/group ownership that shouldn't be changed.